Capacitor package selection for DC-DC convertor
I am currently working on a buck converter design and am in the process of selecting the appropriate capacitor packages for the input and output stages. Could you advise whether 0603 or 0805 package sizes would be more suitable for this application?


Hi
Please provide input and output specifications?

@Tyassin input 5V and output is 0.85V 14A

Have you looked up datasheets, in particular device characteristics showing C(V) curve? What might this information suggest about package size, value, number of parts, etc.?

What is temperature range (ambient, operating, max PCB temp in the local area)?

My advise: Follow the layout example in the datasheet closly.
On page 40 you find this recommendation:

On page 39 you find this description for the capacitors:


thank you very much for the accurate information, would you please also vote on my question?

I have not look in the datasheet if they recommend any capacitor size.
But usually going with ceramic capacitors you have to be aware of the derating of the capacitance do to DC voltage.
On the input side going with 10V capacitors looks good, I would go up in 0805 or even 1206 or 1210 because you will have the high ripple currents in these, so having a low ESR is important.
On the output, the DC voltage looks good. Again go with much higher casing size or you get into thermal problems. I guess with such a low inductance you have a high inductor ripple current and this ripple current is what runs through the output capacitors.
I recommend going through the datasheet and usually they give equations for the capacitor sizes and etc. Then you can based on the derating and the ESR requirements start to select the given capacitances, what case, voltage rating and number of capacitors.

thanks Would you please also vote on my question?
